# Let $H$ be a nonempty set and let $f:H\to\mathbb R$ be such that $f(H)=\{f(h): h \in H\}$ is a bounded subset of $\mathbb R$. Prove that ...

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, supremum-and-infimum

Let $H$ be a nonempty bounded subset of $\mathbb R$ such that $\inf H>0$.

Show that
$\frac1{\inf H} = \sup\{\frac1h : h\in H\}$

Proof:

$\sup\{\frac1h : h\in H\} = \frac1{\inf H}$

By definition, if $H$ is bounded there exists $a,b\in H$ such that $a\leq a_1\leq...x\leq....\leq b$.

\begin{align}\sup\{\frac1h : a\leq x\leq b\} = \frac1{\inf H}\\
\frac1a = \sup\{\frac1h:a\leq x\leq b\}\\
\frac1a = \sup\{\frac1h:a\leq x\leq b\} = \frac1{\inf H}\end{align}

$\inf H = a$ since by definition any $k$ such that $a>k$ implies $k\notin H$.

$\frac1a=\sup\{\frac1h:a\leq x\leq b\} = \frac1{\inf H}=\frac1a$

Comment: I cleaned up your question to my best ability. It still is pretty messy, so please use MathJax to write better questions.

Comment: @DonThousand thank you I'm sorry.

Comment: What's the purpose of $a_1$?

Comment: No.  I'm afraid there is nothing correct about this proof.  $H$ being bounded means that there are $a,b\in \mathbb R$ so that for all $x\in H$ we have $a \le x \le b$ but it does not mean that $a,b \in H$.  Those "..." don't make any sense. $\{\frac 1h:a \le x \le b\}$ doesn't have any set notation meaning.  There is no condition on the $h$ so the set has no definition.  Even if you did you can't claim that $\sup{\frac 1h} = \frac 1{\inf H}$. I don't understand the next two lines. If $a>k$ implies $k\not\in H$ (I don't see why it does) that means $a$ is a lower bound; not nesc. $\inf H$.

Comment: How’s the title related to the question. I see no $f$

Answer (score 1):

Let $$A=\{\frac 1h , h\in H\}$$

$$a\in A \implies$$
$$\exists h\in H \;: a=\frac 1h .$$

$$ h\in H \implies h\ge \inf H>0 \implies$$
$$ a\le\frac{1}{\inf H} $$
thus $\frac{1}{\inf H}$ is an upper bound for $A$.

$\inf H$ is limit of a sequence $(h_n)$ of elements in $H$ with $h_n\ge \inf H>0$.

but
$$\frac{1}{\inf H}=\lim_{n\to+\infty}
\frac{1}{h_n}$$

thus $\frac{1}{\inf H}$ is an upper bound and limit of a sequence of elements in $A$ .
therefore it is the $\sup$.

Comment: Should be $a \leq \frac{1}{\inf H}$.

Comment: @RobertShore Yes of course. thanks.